# How to create Archlinux package from scratch

Tags: arch-linux, packaging

I'm using archlinux and i want to make my own packages with my own modification ,

So , how can i create a new archlinux package with source code and how to modify existing one?

and finally, how to download the binary or source code for archlinux packages like :

```
apt download [package name]
```

or

```
apt source [package name]
```

in debian or ubuntu package manager?

Comment: On ArchLinux you should use packages from ArchLinux. If you want to use ubuntu-package you should use Ubuntu. For download and install packages you can use Pacman ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta will be maybe useful). 
About creating packages please see wiki! https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages

Comment: I know that :) , it's just expamle from ubuntu and debian , and thank you for your replay

Answer (score 6):

Arch Linux packages are built with `makepkg` tool. In order to build a package from scratch you need to create a `PKGBUILD` file which defines package metadata and build steps. This file is essentially a Bash script.

A very basic `PKGBUILD` file could look like this:

```
pkgname=arch-update-notify
pkgver=0.2
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Notify all users with X sessions about available updates with a popup."
arch=("any")
url="https://github.com/zoresvit/arch-update-notify"
license=('MIT')
depends=('libnotify' 'python')
source=("git://github.com/zoresvit/${pkgname}/")
sha1sums=('SKIP')

package() {
    cd "$pkgname"
    mkdir -p $pkgdir/usr/bin
    install -D -m755 ./updates.py $pkgdir/usr/bin/$pkgname
}
```

It creates a package which installs `updates.py` file into `/usr/bin` directory.

For more information see [ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages), which describes in depth how Arch Linux packaging works and how to properly build a package.

There is also an [ArchLinux User Repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages) (AUR) which contains `PKGBUILD` files created by users. You can choose a package and click *view PKGBUILD* to get better idea how others write their `PKGBUILD` files.

You can use `pacman` to download a package:

```
pacman -Sw <package_name>
```

This will download a package with all its dependencies into `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`.

For more information on using `pacman` you can also check out corresponding [ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman).

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to upvote or "accept" the answer (checkmark on the left) if it answered the question.